# Problema Toolbar y ScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Buen día amigos,

Tengo el siguiente problema espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.
Tengo un Toolbar y un ScrollView, lo que quiero es que al momento de tener el foco sobre el EditText, el toolbar no desaparezca de la pantalla de tal manera que el usuario pueda presionar sobre el arrow del Toolbar y volver a la vista anterior aunque el EditText tenga el foco y este habilitado el teclado, este problema me pasa en una pantalla de 240 x320. Agrego mi Layout y la imagen del simulador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El la siguiente imagen, el Toolbar desaparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:hint="titulo"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:theme="@style/LoginTextAppearance">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_email"
                    style="@style/loginEditTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d10dp"
                    android:hint="mi hint"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_divider"
                style="@style/separadorStyle" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/img_btn_sig"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/boton_siguiente"
            android:text="Siguiente"
            />


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3.5">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/d60dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/d60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/d8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/d8dp"

                        />

                </FrameLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_msg_pie"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6.5"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Pie de Página"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/d10_5sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

De antemano gracias,

saludos.

Comment: Que comportamiento exactamente esperas de tu layout? que desaparece el `toolbar` cuando se abre el teclado, o que no desaparece?

Comment: @StefanNolde gracias por responder. Quiero que el Toolbar NO desaparezca cuando salga el teclado

Comment: Entonces es un caso para un `CoordinatorLayout` en vez del `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres mantener tu toolbar a la vista, deberías usar un `CoordinatorLayout`:

Un ejemplo (fijate en `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`, que arregla el tema del scroll ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me gustaría saber para que es esta línea  tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"

Comment: Eso es para el "Lint tool" para ignorar avisos. Probablemente puedes ignorarlo, lo puse mientras estaba experimentando con el código de donde te sacó el ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Saludos